# LoadException with FXML created with Scene Builder 2.0

Tags: javafx-8

I got a problem that i absolutly cant solve on my own because i have just started using JAVA FX. I get a nasty javafx.fxml.LoadException: , but i have done exactly like a guide (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/get_started/jsbpub-get_started.htm), but i cant get my Main to run. This is the console:

```
ant -f P:\\FXML\\IssueTrackingLite jfxsa-run
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: P:\FXML\IssueTrackingLite\build
Updating property file: P:\FXML\IssueTrackingLite\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: P:\FXML\IssueTrackingLite\build\classes
Created dir: P:\FXML\IssueTrackingLite\build\empty
Created dir: P:\FXML\IssueTrackingLite\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 6 source files to P:\FXML\IssueTrackingLite\build\classes
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
1 warning
Copying 4 files to P:\FXML\IssueTrackingLite\build\classes
compile:
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
Launching <fx:jar> task from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar
Warning: From JDK7u25 the Codebase manifest attribute should be used to restrict JAR repurposing.
         Please set manifest.custom.codebase property to override the current default non-secure value '*'.
Launching <fx:deploy> task from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar
jfx-deployment-script:
jfx-deployment:
jar:
Copying 12 files to P:\FXML\IssueTrackingLite\dist\run910302418
jfx-project-run:
Executing P:\FXML\IssueTrackingLite\dist\run910302418\IssueTrackingLite.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre/bin/java
 before ........!
IssueTrackingLiteController.initialize
août 11, 2014 12:24:01 PM issuetrackinglite.Main start
GRAVE: null
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/P:/FXML/IssueTrackingLite/dist/run910302418/IssueTrackingLite.jar!/issuetrackinglite/IssueTrackingLite.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2595)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3230)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3191)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3164)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3140)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3120)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at issuetrackinglite.Main.start(Main.java:55)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at issuetrackinglite.IssueTrackingLiteController.configureTable(IssueTrackingLiteController.java:481)
    at issuetrackinglite.IssueTrackingLiteController.initialize(IssueTrackingLiteController.java:119)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 19 more

BUILD STOPPED (total time: 50 minutes 46 seconds)
```

What does it mean and how can I fix it?

the main class:

```
package issuetrackinglite;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(Main.class, (java.lang.String[])null);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            System.out.println(" before ........!");
            AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("/issuetrackinglite/IssueTrackingLite.fxml"));
            System.out.println(" after .............!");
            Scene scene = new Scene(page);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Issue Tracking Lite Sample");
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code that includes the `initialize()` method. You must use the `initialize()` method when loading from an FXML file to instantiate the components you created in Scene Builder. Also if your FXML file is in the same path as `Main`, you are adding extra directories to the path to the FXML file.

Answer (score 0):

my FXML file is in the same path as Main class.

the class Controller:

```
package issuetrackinglite;
public class IssueTrackingLiteController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    Button newIssue;
    @FXML
    Button deleteIssue;
    @FXML
    Button saveIssue;
    TableView<ObservableIssue> table;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<ObservableIssue, String> colName;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<ObservableIssue, IssueStatus> colStatus;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<ObservableIssue, String> colSynopsis;
    @FXML
    ListView<String> list;
    @FXML
    TextField synopsis;

    private String displayedBugId; // the id of the bug displayed in the details section.
    private String displayedBugProject; // the name of the project of the bug displayed in the detailed section.
    @FXML
    Label displayedIssueLabel; // the displayedIssueLabel will contain a concatenation of the 
                               // the project name and the bug id.
    @FXML
    AnchorPane details;
    @FXML
    TextArea descriptionValue;
    ObservableList<String> projectsView = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    TrackingService model = null;
    private TextField statusValue = new TextField();
    final ObservableList<ObservableIssue> tableContent = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rsrcs) {
        assert colName != null : "fx:id=\"colName\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'IssueTrackingLite.fxml'.";
        assert colStatus != null : "fx:id=\"colStatus\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'IssueTrackingLite.fxml'.";
        assert colSynopsis != null : "fx:id=\"colSynopsis\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'IssueTrackingLite.fxml'.";
        assert deleteIssue != null : "fx:id=\"deleteIssue\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'IssueTrackingLite.fxml'.";
        assert descriptionValue != null : "fx:id=\"descriptionValue\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'IssueTrackingLite.fxml'.";
        assert details != null : "fx:id=\"details\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'IssueTrackingLite.fxml'.";
        assert displayedIssueLabel != null : "fx:id=\"displayedIssueLabel\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'IssueTrackingLite.fxml'.";
        assert newIssue != null : "fx:id=\"newIssue\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'IssueTrackingLite.fxml'.";
        assert saveIssue != null : "fx:id=\"saveIssue\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'IssueTrackingLite.fxml'.";
        assert synopsis != null : "fx:id=\"synopsis\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'IssueTrackingLite.fxml'.";
        assert table != null : "fx:id=\"table\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'IssueTrackingLite.fxml'.";
        assert list != null : "fx:id=\"list\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'IssueTrackingLite.fxml'.";

        System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".initialize");
        configureButtons();
        configureDetails();
        configureTable();
        connectToService();
        if (list != null) {
            list.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
            list.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(projectItemSelected);
            displayedProjectNames.addListener(projectNamesListener);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the NewIssue button is fired.
     *
     * @param event the action event.
     */
    @FXML
    public void newIssueFired(ActionEvent event) {
        final String selectedProject = getSelectedProject();
        if (model != null && selectedProject != null) {
            ObservableIssue issue = model.createIssueFor(selectedProject);
            if (table != null) {
                // Select the newly created issue.
                table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                table.getSelectionModel().select(issue);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the DeleteIssue button is fired.
     *
     * @param event the action event.
     */
    @FXML
    public void deleteIssueFired(ActionEvent event) {
        final String selectedProject = getSelectedProject();
        if (model != null && selectedProject != null && table != null) {
            // We create a copy of the current selection: we can't delete
            //    issue while looping over the live selection, since
            //    deleting selected issues will modify the selection.
            final List<?> selectedIssue = new ArrayList<Object>(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
            for (Object o : selectedIssue) {
                if (o instanceof ObservableIssue) {
                    model.deleteIssue(((ObservableIssue) o).getId());
                }
            }
            table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the SaveIssue button is fired.
     *
     * @param event the action event.
     */
    @FXML
    public void saveIssueFired(ActionEvent event) {
        final ObservableIssue ref = getSelectedIssue();
        final Issue edited = new DetailsData();
        SaveState saveState = computeSaveState(edited, ref);
        if (saveState == SaveState.UNSAVED) {
            model.saveIssue(ref.getId(), edited.getStatus(),
                    edited.getSynopsis(), edited.getDescription());
        }
        // We refresh the content of the table because synopsis and/or description
        // are likely to have been modified by the user.
        int selectedRowIndex = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        table.getItems().clear();
        displayedIssues = model.getIssueIds(getSelectedProject());
        for (String id : displayedIssues) {
            final ObservableIssue issue = model.getIssue(id);
            table.getItems().add(issue);
        }
        table.getSelectionModel().select(selectedRowIndex);

        updateSaveIssueButtonState();
    }

    private void configureButtons() {
        if (newIssue != null) {
            newIssue.setDisable(true);
        }
        if (saveIssue != null) {
            saveIssue.setDisable(true);
        }
        if (deleteIssue != null) {
            deleteIssue.setDisable(true);
        }
    }

    // An observable list of project names obtained from the model.
    // This is a live list, and we will react to its changes by removing
    // and adding project names to/from our list widget.
    private ObservableList<String> displayedProjectNames;

    // The list of Issue IDs relevant to the selected project. Can be null
    // if no project is selected. This list is obtained from the model.
    // This is a live list, and we will react to its changes by removing
    // and adding Issue objects to/from our table widget.
    private ObservableList<String> displayedIssues;

    // This listener will listen to changes in the displayedProjectNames list,
    // and update our list widget in consequence.
    private final ListChangeListener<String> projectNamesListener = new ListChangeListener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change<? extends String> c) {
            if (projectsView == null) {
                return;
            }
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasAdded() || c.wasReplaced()) {
                    for (String p : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                        projectsView.add(p);
                    }
                }
                if (c.wasRemoved() || c.wasReplaced()) {
                    for (String p : c.getRemoved()) {
                        projectsView.remove(p);
                    }
                }
            }
            FXCollections.sort(projectsView);
        }
    };

    // This listener will listen to changes in the displayedIssues list,
    // and update our table widget in consequence.
    private final ListChangeListener<String> projectIssuesListener = new ListChangeListener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change<? extends String> c) {
            if (table == null) {
                return;
            }
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasAdded() || c.wasReplaced()) {
                    for (String p : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                        table.getItems().add(model.getIssue(p));
                    }
                }
                if (c.wasRemoved() || c.wasReplaced()) {
                    for (String p : c.getRemoved()) {
                        ObservableIssue removed = null;
                        // Issue already removed:
                        // we can't use model.getIssue(issueId) to get it.
                        // we need to loop over the table content instead.
                        // Then we need to remove it - but outside of the for loop
                        // to avoid ConcurrentModificationExceptions.
                        for (ObservableIssue t : table.getItems()) {
                            if (t.getId().equals(p)) {
                                removed = t;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (removed != null) {
                            table.getItems().remove(removed);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // Connect to the model, get the project's names list, and listen to
    // its changes. Initializes the list widget with retrieved project names.
    private void connectToService() {
        if (model == null) {
            model = new TrackingServiceStub();
            displayedProjectNames = model.getProjectNames();
        }
        projectsView.clear();
        List<String> sortedProjects = new ArrayList<String>(displayedProjectNames);
        Collections.sort(sortedProjects);
        projectsView.addAll(sortedProjects);
        list.setItems(projectsView);
    }

    // This listener listen to changes in the table widget selection and
    // update the DeleteIssue button state accordingly.
    private final ListChangeListener<ObservableIssue> tableSelectionChanged =
            new ListChangeListener<ObservableIssue>() {

                @Override
                public void onChanged(Change<? extends ObservableIssue> c) {
                    updateDeleteIssueButtonState();
                    updateBugDetails();
                    updateSaveIssueButtonState();
                }
            };

    private static String nonNull(String s) {
        return s == null ? "" : s;
    }

    private void updateBugDetails() {
        final ObservableIssue selectedIssue = getSelectedIssue();
        if (details != null && selectedIssue != null) {
            if (displayedIssueLabel != null) {
                displayedBugId = selectedIssue.getId();
                displayedBugProject = selectedIssue.getProjectName();
                displayedIssueLabel.setText( displayedBugId + " / " + displayedBugProject );
            }
            if (synopsis != null) {
                synopsis.setText(nonNull(selectedIssue.getSynopsis()));
            }
            if (statusValue != null) {
                statusValue.setText(selectedIssue.getStatus().toString());
            }
            if (descriptionValue != null) {
                descriptionValue.selectAll();
                descriptionValue.cut();
                descriptionValue.setText(selectedIssue.getDescription());
            }
        } else {
            displayedIssueLabel.setText("");
            displayedBugId = null;
            displayedBugProject = null;
        }
        if (details != null) {
            details.setVisible(selectedIssue != null);
        }
    }

    private boolean isVoid(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof String) {
            return isEmpty((String) o);
        } else {
            return o == null;
        }
    }

    private boolean isEmpty(String s) {
        return s == null || s.trim().isEmpty();
    }

    private boolean equal(Object o1, Object o2) {
        if (isVoid(o1)) {
            return isVoid(o2);
        }
        return o1.equals(o2);
    }

    private static enum SaveState {

        INVALID, UNSAVED, UNCHANGED
    }

    private final class DetailsData implements Issue {

        @Override
        public String getId() {
            if (displayedBugId == null || isEmpty(displayedIssueLabel.getText())) {
                return null;
            }
            return displayedBugId;
        }

        @Override
        public IssueStatus getStatus() {
            if (statusValue == null || isEmpty(statusValue.getText())) {
                return null;
            }
            return IssueStatus.valueOf(statusValue.getText().trim());
        }

        @Override
        public String getProjectName() {
            if (displayedBugProject == null || isEmpty(displayedIssueLabel.getText())) {
                return null;
            }
            return displayedBugProject;
        }

        @Override
        public String getSynopsis() {
            if (synopsis == null || isEmpty(synopsis.getText())) {
                return "";
            }
            return synopsis.getText();
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            if (descriptionValue == null || isEmpty(descriptionValue.getText())) {
                return "";
            }
            return descriptionValue.getText();
        }
    }

    private SaveState computeSaveState(Issue edited, Issue issue) {
        try {
            // These fields are not editable - so if they differ they are invalid
            // and we cannot save.
            if (!equal(edited.getId(), issue.getId())) {
                return SaveState.INVALID;
            }
            if (!equal(edited.getProjectName(), issue.getProjectName())) {
                return SaveState.INVALID;
            }

            // If these fields differ, the issue needs saving.
            if (!equal(edited.getStatus(), issue.getStatus())) {
                return SaveState.UNSAVED;
            }
            if (!equal(edited.getSynopsis(), issue.getSynopsis())) {
                return SaveState.UNSAVED;
            }
            if (!equal(edited.getDescription(), issue.getDescription())) {
                return SaveState.UNSAVED;
            }
        } catch (Exception x) {
            // If there's an exception, some fields are invalid.
            return SaveState.INVALID;
        }
        // No field is invalid, no field needs saving.
        return SaveState.UNCHANGED;
    }

    private void updateDeleteIssueButtonState() {
        boolean disable = true;
        if (deleteIssue != null && table != null) {
            final boolean nothingSelected = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().isEmpty();
            disable = nothingSelected;
        }
        if (deleteIssue != null) {
            deleteIssue.setDisable(disable);
        }
    }

    private void updateSaveIssueButtonState() {
        boolean disable = true;
        if (saveIssue != null && table != null) {
            final boolean nothingSelected = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().isEmpty();
            disable = nothingSelected;
        }
        if (disable == false) {
            disable = computeSaveState(new DetailsData(), getSelectedIssue()) != SaveState.UNSAVED;
        }
        if (saveIssue != null) {
            saveIssue.setDisable(disable);
        }
    }

    // Configure the table widget: set up its column, and register the
    // selection changed listener.
    private void configureTable() {
        colName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ObservableIssue, String>("id"));
        colSynopsis.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ObservableIssue, String>("synopsis"));
        colStatus.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ObservableIssue, IssueStatus>("status"));

        // In order to limit the amount of setup in Getting Started we set the width
        // of the 3 columns programmatically but one can do it from SceneBuilder.
        colName.setPrefWidth(75);
        colStatus.setPrefWidth(75);
        colSynopsis.setPrefWidth(443);

        colName.setMinWidth(75);
        colStatus.setMinWidth(75);
        colSynopsis.setMinWidth(443);

        colName.setMaxWidth(750);
        colStatus.setMaxWidth(750);
        colSynopsis.setMaxWidth(4430);

        table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);

        table.setItems(tableContent);
        assert table.getItems() == tableContent;

        final ObservableList<ObservableIssue> tableSelection = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

        tableSelection.addListener(tableSelectionChanged);
    }

    /**
     * Return the name of the project currently selected, or null if no project
     * is currently selected.
     *
     */
    public String getSelectedProject() {
        if (model != null && list != null) {
            final ObservableList<String> selectedProjectItem = list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
            final String selectedProject = selectedProjectItem.get(0);
            return selectedProject;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public ObservableIssue getSelectedIssue() {
        if (model != null && table != null) {
            List<ObservableIssue> selectedIssues = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
            if (selectedIssues.size() == 1) {
                final ObservableIssue selectedIssue = selectedIssues.get(0);
                return selectedIssue;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Listen to changes in the list selection, and updates the table widget and
     * DeleteIssue and NewIssue buttons accordingly.
     */
    private final ChangeListener<String> projectItemSelected = new ChangeListener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            projectUnselected(oldValue);
            projectSelected(newValue);
        }
    };

    // Called when a project is unselected.
    private void projectUnselected(String oldProjectName) {
        if (oldProjectName != null) {
            displayedIssues.removeListener(projectIssuesListener);
            displayedIssues = null;
            table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            table.getItems().clear();
            if (newIssue != null) {
                newIssue.setDisable(true);
            }
            if (deleteIssue != null) {
                deleteIssue.setDisable(true);
            }
        }
    }

    // Called when a project is selected.
    private void projectSelected(String newProjectName) {
        if (newProjectName != null) {
            table.getItems().clear();
            displayedIssues = model.getIssueIds(newProjectName);
            for (String id : displayedIssues) {
                final ObservableIssue issue = model.getIssue(id);
                table.getItems().add(issue);
            }
            displayedIssues.addListener(projectIssuesListener);
            if (newIssue != null) {
                newIssue.setDisable(false);
            }
            updateDeleteIssueButtonState();
            updateSaveIssueButtonState();
        }
    }

    private void configureDetails() {
        if (details != null) {
            details.setVisible(false);
        }

        if (details != null) {
            details.addEventFilter(EventType.ROOT, new EventHandler<Event>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(Event event) {
                    if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED
                            || event.getEventType() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) {
                        updateSaveIssueButtonState();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is the varaiable: TableView<ObservableIssue> table; see class controller; no annotation @FXML before this variable.

Comment: Each component has to have it's own @FXML above when declaring to let it know that it is already contained within the FXML file. Notice your controller file, `TableView<ObservableIssue> table;` has no @FXML before it.

Comment: I mean it must have `@FXML` annotation if the component is within the FXML file, if you created the `TableView` in Scene Builder. I assume you did, as the columns are!!